# JavaScript, create div with link and then remove by clicking said div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a vanilla javascript that creates one div or more when clicking on a specific link. When said div has appeared I want to be able to remove it by clicking on that div.

So far I've successfully made it so that a div is created when clicking a link.

The HTML:

```
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#" id="create-div">Click me!</a>
        <div id="target"></div>
    </div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var createTarget = document.getElementById('target');
    var link = document.getElementById('create-div');

    function createDiv() {
        var content = '<div id="clickme"><div class="main"><div class="secondary"></div></div></div>';
        createTarget.innerHTML = content;
    }

    link.addEventListener("click", function() {
        createDiv();
    });

})();
```

What I can't figure out is how to remove the div by clicking on it after it has been created? Bear in mind that I am new and trying to learn vanilla JavaScript for now. I know about jQuery and all the other libraries, but I'd rather just learn the basic JavaScript to begin with.

Through the power of Google I've found out about "removeChild" but I am yet to find out how to get it to work on a div by clicking it.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you'll need to add the listener to delete it in the function where it's created, after the div is created.

Comment: `el.remove();` will work in newer browsers. `el.parentNode.removeChild(el)` will work most places

Comment: @Nit I'm sorry you feel that way. I searched a lot and the questions I found were all answered with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :

```
  createTarget.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('clickme'); // to get the id of the div that dynamically created
        elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem); // function removes specified child node of your specified element.
    });
```

see this working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5wc2z763/1/)

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks sir for your comment, I tried to edit my answer and add comment to explain a little.

Comment: I tried it and it works. However I can't get the div to show again when clicking the link after making it disappear. And also it only seems to be working for one div.

If I copy the text and rename vars and functions to work like they're completely new and individual from the first ones, then I get two links and two divs. I can click either link and the new div pops up. When I click the div it disappears as requested. But after clicking one of the links the other link won't work.

Comment: Ok  @Chi ,try http://jsfiddle.net/5wc2z763/1/ its working with two link and div is showing and removing as you desire. On your fiddle above, your creating a different var, but the <div> id is the same.